# UWP/C# change value of run time added control

Tags: c#, scope, uwp, controls

I'm adding items to ListView during run time.

OnClick button adds one TextBlock to ListView. Here is code:

```
private async void addPlayerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid g = new Grid();
        ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c1.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        c2.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);

        PlayersName dialog2 = new PlayersName();
        var result2 = await dialog2.ShowAsync();
        if(result2 == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            RowDefinition ri = new RowDefinition();
            ri.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
            g.RowDefinitions.Add(ri);
            TextBlock label = new TextBlock();
            TextBlock counter = new TextBlock();
            counter.Text = "0";
            label.Text = dialog2.Text;
            g.Children.Add(label);
            g.Children.Add(counter);
            Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(counter, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(counter, 1);
        }

            list.Items.Add(g);

    }
```

And all of that works as it should.

But, how can I later change value of Text for, let's say, control named counter? I have to do that from another function, and also, it looks like I have more than one control named counter, because each time a button is clicked (addPlayerButton_Click), an instance of `counter` is added.

How do I keep track of controls added at runtime?

Comment: `how can i change value of Text for, let's say, control named counter` counter.Text = "0", you have this line in your code.  `I have to do that from another function` why do you think so?  `it looks like i have more than one control named counter`  Ok, tell us about each of them.

Comment: each time I click on button it calls this method. So, I have more than one control named counter.

Comment: Ok, you have more than one control for which the referring **local variable name** is `counter`. Note that it doesn't mean you have multiple controls that go by the **Name** of `counter`. One option is to give each of them a name, like counter.Name = "something" (each time different). Or put them under a common parent, like a Panel and refer with `panel.Controls`.

Comment: I need to change value of that control from another function, it's a different action from different button. I know how to change value. but that control is not available from outside this scope.

Comment: That's why you don't use local variable to reference it. Either make a class level variable, which can be list, dictionary or otherwise. Each time a button is clicked, add your local reference to it, to keep track of all added counter controls. Or give each of them a Name, you'll then look up via Controls (hierarchy lookup, use built-in methods, recursion or else it'll get complicated quickly), or using a common Parent (flat lookup using built-in methods).

Comment: hmm, all of these contorls allready have parent - Grid. But, it looks like g.Controls does not work on uwp. am i wrong?

Comment: I have no experience with UWP. The options I explained apply in WinForms. You should still have a class level variable option, if nothing else works.

Comment: @Neolisk thank you for your help. parent.FindName("controlName") is what works as it should.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Please copy your last comment underneath my answer, to let future visitors know which part of my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one control for which the referring **local variable name** is `counter`. Note that it doesn't mean you have multiple controls that go by the Name of `counter`. One option is to give each of them a name (each time different), like

```
counter.Name = "something"
```

Or put them under a common parent, like a Panel. You can also make a class level variable (list, dictionary or similar). Each time a button is clicked, add your local reference to it.

Comment: thank you for your help. parent.FindName("controlName") is what works as it should.